# Laravel 5.5 modify URL before redirect

Tags: redirect, laravel-5.5

I have link like `http://website.loc/belaya-cerkov/feedback/thank-you` but I want to convert it to `http://website.loc/Belaya-cerkov/feedback/thank-you`, where the best place to do this manipulation in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You should do such manipulation in Web Server. If you're using Apache, you can define it in your `.htaccess` in your public folder.
But I'm not sure why you must doing something like that.